# Unique table by 1 column

Tags: mysql

I have such structure: table `hits` with the following sample data:

```
page_alpha_id   ok_id               ip
-------------   ------------    -----------
zfuUnu4K11R9C   100255884520    95.73.30.67
wL77qKOmSTFW    100279470528    91.39.146.76
OArxea90        100307614632    176.50.251.94
wefweffew       100307614632    126.40.251.94
yuSb4zzRs       100326443828    93.88.21.86
OxyCtgwlwRFX    100356656755    93.223.88.254
ukwY8SpBT5crX   100375258476    81.4.193.238
ifmgtm7QC       100488290479    95.71.3.15
```

How can I `DELETE` rows with duplicates in column `ok_id`?

It doesn't matter which row is deleted.

Comment: If it doesn't matter, then likely you have bigger problems!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delete` with `join`, assuming one of the other columns has distinct values for each `ok_id`.  For instance:

```
delete h
    from hits h join
         (select ok_id, max(page_alpha_id) as maxpad
          from hits h
          group by ok_id
         ) hmax
         on h.ok_id = hmax.ok_id and h.page_alpha_id < hmax.maxpad;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the special join syntax for delete:

```
delete a
from hits a
join hits b on a.ok_id = b.ok_id
  and a.page_alpha_id > b.page_alpha_id
```

The "trick" that makes this work is the extra greater-than condition which both prevents rows from joining to themselves and picks only on side of the join.